# Callbacks raises stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback

I need to run callbacks for :assign_state and :state_closed but they aren't work and raises

```
Stack level to deep
```

Ticket.rb

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :default_values
  after_update :state_closed
  after_create :assign_state

  attr_accessible :description, :title, :employee_department_id, :user_id, :first_name,
   :last_name , :email, :state_id, :employee_id, :ticket_state, :assign_state


  belongs_to :employee_department
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :employee

  has_many :replies

  def default_values
    self.state_id = 3 if self.state_id.nil?
  end

  def to_label
    ticket_state.to_s
  end

  def state_closed
    if self.ticket_state == "Solved" || self.ticket_state == "Canceled" 
      self.ticket_state = "Closed"
      self.save
    end
  end

def assign_state
  if self.employee_id.nil?
    self.assign_state = "Un-assigned"
  else 
    self.assign_state = "Assigned"
  end 
  self.save
end

   Ticket.all.each do |ticket|
    if ticket.ticket_state.blank?
      ticket.ticket_state = 'open'
    end
    ticket.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assign_state calls itself in an infinite recursion : it calls `#save`, which in turn triggers the `#assign_state` callback.

Comment: my callbacks not working and no error raises , could you help me please ?

Comment: What callback in particular? All of them? How do you trigger them? You said assign_state was raising 'stack level' error, why it is not called anymore?

Comment: it was a problem because of capital letters but its solved now. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `before_update`callback if you don't call `save`or use `update_attributes` in the callback.

```
before_update :state_closed

def state_closed
  if self.ticket_state == "Solved" || self.ticket_state == "Canceled" 
    self.ticket_state = "Closed"
  end
end
```

This will update ticket_state and the original update call will udpate it. So this way update is only called once.